# Using jQuery to change headings, and the SEO effect

Tags: jquery, web-crawler, heading

I'm using a WP theme that uses `<div>` to print some titles (for services for instance). So I decided to use some jQuery code and replace the `<div>` with headings in order to have my page more friendly for SEO. The code I'm using is as followed:

```
$('.THE_TITLE_IN_QUESTION').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<h2 />", {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

Since this line of code is executed **after** the page is loaded, I need to know what the crawlers see when they visit my web page? Do they see and index the page with the initial `<div>` tag as generated by default, or do they see my defined heading?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Really it depends on the crawler. If I'm not mistaken, most crawlers for big search engines do index JavaScript, although there can be other factors. I would recommend taking a look at [this](https://moz.com/blog/javascript-seo) blog post to see what those factors are and how to mitigate them. I hope this is helpful!